# Regex Expressions in Dart/Flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am developing an app with markdown capabilities, so I am building a lexer to handle this. I am fairly new to Flutter and have little experience with Regex in general.

Essentially there is a difference between `*text*`, `**text**`, and `***text***`.

My expressions right now are:

```
r"\B\*[A-Za-z0-9 ]+\*\B"
r"\B\*{2}[A-Za-z0-9 ]+\*{2}\B"
r"\B\*{3}[A-Za-z0-9 ]+\*{3}\B"
```

The issue is that the first expression is matching the other two. `**text***` will get matched also with the second expression. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You can exclude it with lookarounds `(?<!\*)\*[A-Za-z0-9 ]+\*(?!\*)` and `(?<!\*)\*\*[A-Za-z0-9 ]+\*\*(?!\*)` etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could use:

```
(?<!\S)(\*{1,3})[A-Za-z0-9 ]+\1(?!\S)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eTR9HT/1)

- `(?<!\S)` - Assert position is not preceded by anything that is not a whitespace char;
- `(\*{1,3})` - Match 1-3 asterisk characters;
- `[A-Za-z0-9 ]+` - Match 1+ characters from given character class;
- `\1` - Backreference what is matched in 1st group;
- `(?!\S)` - Assert position is not followed by anything other than whitespace char.

---

Note that if you'd remove the final negative lookahead you could also match `**text**` in `**test***` if that is what you were after. Or even remove the leading negative lookbehind to match `**text**` in `****text** test`

Comment: As an explanation to why the initial patterns did not yield the right result, you might add that the `\B` matches between two `**` as there is a non word boundary in between.

Comment: Note sure if it is applicable for the OP, but when I mark something bold for example in a SO answer like this t**esti**ng it also works. In that case the lookarounds could be excluding the asterix `(?!\*)`

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean @Thefourthbird. Please leave these comments for a little while for OP to take notice.